# Matching Python and GRASS projection

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass-7.0, matplotlib-basemap

I have a colleague producing maps with the following Python Basemap projection:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
m = Basemap(width=6000000,height=3900000,
        resolution='l',projection='eqdc',\
        lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=38,lon_0=-97.)
print(m.proj4string)
```

With a `proj4` string of:

```
+y_0=1949999.9999999986 +units=m +lon_0=-97.0 +x_0=3000000.0000000014 +proj=eqdc +lat_0=38.0 +R=6370997.0 +lat_2=55.0 +lat_1=45.0
```

I'd like to match this in GRASS.

```
 g.proj -c proj4="proj4string from above" location=EQDC
```

Gives an error:

```
WARNING: Datum <unknown> not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
Location <EQDC> created
```

I'm used to working in GRASS and using projections defined by GeoTIFF files, reprojecting, etc. I've created custom views in Python like above. But have not yet figured out how to tell GRASS to create something with the detail that I can in Python.

Comment: Try `+proj=eqdc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=-97 +lat_1=45 +lat_2=55 +x_0=3000000 +y_0=1950000 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs`. This works with QGIS, maybe GRASS too.

Comment: Same error. Seems to be the same string but with some numbers rounded?

Comment: I took your string as a custom CRS in QGIS, and saved a WGS84 dataset to it. Have you tried the string in the GRASS GUI? I get no error message, and can see the shapefile created in QGIS in that projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can match the two if I add a `datum` and remove the `x_0` and `y_0` parameters to/from the `proj4` string:

In GRASS:

```
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=eqdc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=-97 +lat_1=45 +lat_2=55 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs +datum=wgs84" location=EQDC
g.mapset mapset=PERMANENT location=EQDC

g.region -l
g.region e=e+2500000 w=w-2500000 n=n+2000000 s=s-2000000 res=1000
```